# when i changed orientation portrait to landscape i want layout should change for landscape and video is start from same position in android?

Tags: android

This is my whole code for media player only the problem is when i changed the orientation video is playing from beginning what should i do.I also add the "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" in menifest. please help

```
//MediaPlayerActivity.java

package com.focusmedica.ud_en_acne;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MediaPlayerActivity extends Activity implements   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
ImageView pauseAndResume,refresh,next,prev,screenshot,pencil;
SeekBar videoProgress;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private Utilities util;
TextView current;
boolean playFlag,isTrue=false;
VideoView videoView;
int vDuration;
LinearLayout linear;
RelativeLayout relate;
View mView;
private Paint mPaint;
private Canvas mCanvas;
/*static int[] video_url=new int[]{
        R.raw.introduction,R.raw.causes,R.raw.risk_factors,R.raw.types_of_acne,
        R.raw.signs_and_symptoms,R.raw.treatment,R.raw.prevention_and_self_care,
};*/
int video_url=R.raw.introduction;
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "Pictures/screenshot.png";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

    videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoProgress=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    videoProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    pauseAndResume=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnPauseResume);
    relate=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relate);
    linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    screenshot=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnScreenshot);
    refresh=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
    pencil=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnPencil);
    current=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.current);
    linear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    util = new Utilities();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int position = extras.getInt("position");

    final Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+  video_url);

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+  video_url));
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    vDuration = Integer.parseInt(time );

    relate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (linear.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 100);
            }else{
                linear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isTrue == true) {
                relate.removeView(mView);
                mView = new DrawingView(MediaPlayerActivity.this);
                relate.addView(mView);
            }
        }
    });

    pencil.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isTrue==false) {
                mView = new DrawingView(MediaPlayerActivity.this);
                relate.addView(mView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                init();
                isTrue=true;
            }else if(isTrue==true){
                relate.removeView(mView);
                isTrue=false;
            }
        }
    });

    pauseAndResume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pauseAndResume.getDrawable().getConstantState()== getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause).getConstantState())
            {
                videoView.pause();
                pauseAndResume.setImageResource(R.drawable.play1);
            }
            else
            {
                videoView.start();
                pauseAndResume.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
        }
    });

    screenshot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot(MediaPlayerActivity.this,uri);
            saveBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });

    playVideo(uri);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration =vDuration;
    int currentPosition = util.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    videoView.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

//canvas
private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
}


private Bitmap takeScreenshot(Context context, Uri uri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediametadataretriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        mediametadataretriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
        Bitmap bitmap = mediametadataretriever.getFrameAtTime(videoView.getCurrentPosition()*1000);
        Bitmap mainBitmap= ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, videoView.getWidth(), videoView.getHeight(), 2);
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(videoView.getWidth(), videoView.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());
        relate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap1=relate.getDrawingCache();
        mCanvas=new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mainBitmap,new Matrix(), null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0,0, null);
        if(null != mainBitmap)
        {
            return bmOverlay;
        }
        return bmOverlay;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        try
        {
            mediametadataretriever.release();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e) { }
    }
}

private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos =new FileOutputStream(path);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        sentmail(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void sentmail(String path) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[]{"p.ashish029@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Acne");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "Screenshot of image");
    emailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

}

public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = vDuration;
        long currentDuration = videoView.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying Total Duration time
        //total.setText(""+util.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        current.setText(""+util.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int)(util.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        videoProgress.setProgress(progress);

        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

private void playVideo(Uri uri) {

    if (videoView.isPlaying() )
    {
        videoView.stopPlayback();
    }

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();
    updateProgressBar();
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playFlag=false;
            finish();
        }
    });
}

//Canvas
private class DrawingView extends View {

    private Path path;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        path = new Path();
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relate.getWidth(), relate.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    private ArrayList<PathWithPaint> _graphics1 = new ArrayList<PathWithPaint>();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        PathWithPaint pp = new PathWithPaint();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            pp.setPath(path);
            pp.setmPaint(mPaint);
            _graphics1.add(pp);
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (_graphics1.size() > 0) {
            canvas.drawPath(
                    _graphics1.get(_graphics1.size() - 1).getPath(),
                    _graphics1.get(_graphics1.size() - 1).getmPaint());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    onCreate(new Bundle());
 }
}
```

Comment: You can store the current position on `saveInstanceState` and when the orientation changes, restore that value and continue playing from that position
?

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a way to store current states and retrieve them when orientation changes.

Override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method in your activity and save the state of the video you are playing,

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save current video progress
    savedInstanceState.putLong("videoProgress", videoView.getProgress());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and in your `onCreate()` method you can retrieve video progress as,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);first

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentProgress = savedInstanceState.getLong("videoProgress");
        videoView.setProgress(currentProgress);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: where we have to call this method onSaveInstanceState and how ? because for restart the activity we have to call onCreate(new Bundle()) and after that  currentprogress value will again 0.

Comment: @AshishKumarPal I have mentioned already that you should override that method in your activity class. In your case you should write it in `MediaPlayerActivity ` class.

Comment: I am getting previous position upon change the orientation but video is still playing from beginning i am not able to set the progress of videoview in my code. bro what should i do....please help

Comment: thanks using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState i am able to done this....thanks once again